# Deploy to Azure using Storage Account created in new portal

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-deployment

I want to deploy cloud service to Azure, but when deploying must select Storage Account(tried both in new portal and in Visual Studio 2015). My storage account was created using new portal "Storage accounts" and was assigned to some Resource group, as a result I can't choose it when deploying. Any suggestions how to deploy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possible reason is that the storage account created by the new portal was likely created under the resource manager deployment model, while the cloud service is still under the classic deployment model. These don't play well together. You can read a little more at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-deployment-model/. I don't think that a cloud service can use a resource manager storage account for deployment.

In the new portal look at the All Resources blade. If the storage account has a green icon it is a resource manager account. If the storage account has a blue icon it's a classic account.

Create a new storage account as a classic account, either by creating it in the older portal or by using the drop down in the new portal before you click create on the blade that talks about the storage accounts (the before you provide the account name, etc.).  Once you do this then I think the account show show up as an option for your cloud service to deploy with.

Also note that if the storage account was created just prior to trying to select it, it might take a minute or two to become visible as an option.

Comment: Thank you, have read all edits of your answer. In my case it's newly created Cloud service using new portal, also Storage account is not classic. It's not an option to create Storage account using old portal because I want it in same Resource group.

Comment: I think the issue is the storage account is not classic, but the cloud service is. You can't create a cloud server using "resource manager". Creating a cloud service in the new portal still creates a classic Cloud Service. If you create a classic storage account using the new portal in the same resource group does it then appear (after a few mins anyway)?

Comment: Yes, both cloud service and storage account appear in resource group. But when I navigate to my cloud service -> Update -> Storage account(required field) it's not there.

Comment: Being in the same resource group is one thing, both being "Classic" is another. You mentioned the storage account was "not" classic.  Have you verified that if you create a "classic" storage account in the same resource group from the new portal (make sure to select classic on the creation blade before you are prompted for the name, etc.) that it doesn't show up for the cloud service as an option? if so, then you should report this as a bug to https://twitter.com/AzureSupport or file a bug report.

Comment: @MikeWo - hey I have the same problem however - tried storage via classic portal and new one (with classic selected from drop down). It still wont show up on my drop down on Visual Studio. Is there a doco that you could point me to? I spent way too much time on this already :(

Comment: @Luke What version of Studio are you using and where in Studio is the drop down you are talking about?

Comment: @MikeWo 2015, When you click right click on ARM project and click to create new deployment. http://puu.sh/mqpIi/b97f5a783d.png

Comment: Thanks a bunch Mike. It was driving me crazy. I had a classic cloud service, and a storage as resource manager, and didn't understand why they wouldn't play together. Changing the storage to classic worked :)

Comment: Hey guys, does anyone then know how to create a non classic cloud service? Honestly cant see how you can create a non classic version. Obviously would prefer to use non classic in order to get new features as they release

Comment: @David A non-classic Cloud Service doesn't exist. Cloud services are considered "legacy" and new features will not be appearing." Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm for more information about choosing between compute options. Cloud Services can still be used and are supported, but note that new features won't likely be added to them anymore.